# access regex capturing groups in python

Tags: python, regex

`ptx` captures most of what i want. Because i am incompetent at combining many things into one regex) i created a second `ptx1` regex that should capture the following character sequences ADDITIONALLY:
`One Department`, `One foreign Department`, `Two office`

```
    text_list = [' something\npatternx: text_i_want One Department',' something patternx: text_i_want One foreign Department',' something\n patternx: text_i_want Two office']
    text_list = ' '.join(map(str, text_list))
    ptx = re.compile(r'(\s+something(?:\s+|\\n)*patternx:)(.*)(One\s+foreign)', flags = re.DOTALL)
    ten = ptx.search(text_list)
    try:
        if ten:
            ten = ten.group(2)
        else:
            ten = None
    except:
        pass
```

My **question** is: What do i need to do in order to get the `(.*)` or `text_i_want` content returned? I have the gut feeling that i need to access the `eleven` as if it were a list because it has so many capturing groups by `eleven[0].group(1)` in order to get first element from the list and get its second group. But that didnt work either.

You can think of `text_list` like this

```
text_list = ['...something\npatternx: text_i_want One Department',
'...something patternx: text_i_want One foreign Department',
'...something\n patternx: text_i_want Two office']
```

Update

```
    text_list = [' something\npatternx: text_i_want One Department',' something patternx: text_i_want One foreign Department',' something\n patternx: text_i_want Two office']
    text_list = ' '.join(map(str, text_list))
    ptx = re.compile(r'\bsomething\s+patternx:(.*?)\b(?:One\s+(?:Department|foreign(?:\s+Department)?)|Two\s+office)\b', flags = re.DOTALL)
    ten = ptx.search(text_list)
    try:
        if ten:
            ten = ten.group(2)
        else:
            ten = None
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you got tricked when factoring in the alternatives on the right hand side.

You need to use

```py
\bsomething\s+patternx:(.*?)\b(?:One\s+foreign|One\s+Department|One\s+foreign\s+Department|Two\s+office)\b
```

which can be shortened as

```py
\bsomething\s+patternx:(.*?)\b(?:One\s+(?:Department|foreign(?:\s+Department)?)|Two\s+office)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rmlhNP/2). *Details*:

- `\bsomething\s+patternx:` - whole word `something`, one or more whitespaces, `patternx:` string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `\b(?:One\s+(?:Department|foreign(?:\s+Department)?)|Two\s+office)\b` - either `One Department`, `One foreign`, `One foreign Department`, or `Two office` as whole words.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/dVpBAk):

```py
import re
text_list = [' something\npatternx: text_i_want One Department',' something patternx: text_i_want One foreign Department',' something\n patternx: text_i_want Two office']
text_list = ' '.join(map(str, text_list))
rx = r'\bsomething\s+patternx:(.*?)\b(?:One\s+(?:Department|foreign(?:\s+Department)?)|Two\s+office)\b'
print(re.findall(rx, text_list, re.DOTALL))
# => [' text_i_want ', ' text_i_want ', ' text_i_want ']
```